# How can I run my django application using HTTPS Protocol on the Local machine

Tags: python-3.x, django, https

I am trying to load my local site using the HTTPS protocol instead of the insecure http. I have used RunServerPlus extension package of the Django Extensions. I have installed the Django Extensions, the Werkzeug, and pyOpenSSL.
When I load the runserver_plus --cert-file cert.crt, the mysite.com does not load at all.

- Could someone help me here please?

Here is the django-extensions installed

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
# ...
 'django_extensions',
]
```

Here are the ALLOWED_HOSTS[]

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mysite.com', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, add `127.0.0.1 mysite.com` to your system **hosts** file:

> path: C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

Edit allowed host on django settings.py:

> ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["mysite.com", "127.0.0.1", "localhost"]

If this did not resolve your problem, restart your pc.

If that still doesn't help, [read here](https://serverfault.com/questions/452268/hosts-file-ignored-how-to-troubleshoot).

### Note:

**Do not use a proxy or vpn on your pc**, or turn them off. They mess up with hosts custom domain resolution.